# Debugging Windows XP kernel using 1394 connection

Tags: windows, debugging, kernel, windbg, firewire

Host: Windows 7 x64

Guest: Windows XP SP3 x86

I got 2 PCI firewire cards on both ends (SIIG 1394 installed as Texas Instruments OHCI Compliant IEEE 1394 Host Controller).

On Windows XP I added the following to boot.ini:
/debug /debugport=1394 /channel=10

I rebooted Windows XP and OHCI driver got yellow banged (which is expected).

On Windows 7 (host) I run WinDBG(x86), open kernel debug, 1394, specify channel 10 and run

It says:

> Using 1394 for debugging
>
> Checking 1394 debug driver version.
>
> Opened \.\DBG1394_INSTANCE10
>
> Timer Resolution set to 1000 usec.
>
> Waiting to reconnect...

Nothing happens. (1394 Windows Kernel mode driver is installed).

On each firewire card I got 3 ports, but I am not sure whether it matter which one needs to be used.

Please advise what might be wrong in the configuration above.

How can test 1394 connection independently ?

Comment: Most 1394 debugging problems are caused by using multiple 1394 controllers in either the host or target computer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556866(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had no multiple OHCI controllers on either end.

Finally, by simply exchanging components one by one, I have identified that the issue was caused by malfunctioning Firewire cable.  It was not visually damaged, but it looked like it was accidentally used for something else except Firewire ports.

Unfortunately, it took time to identify the root cause since Microsoft doesn't provide any utility to ensure physical connection between both machines.